# can you send custom data to the accept.js handler?

Tags: authorize.net, accept.js

When dispatching the secure data: `Accept.dispatchData(secureData, callback);`

is there a way to send custom data along with the secureData to your callback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, userFields would be included in the createTransactionRequest after receiving the nonce.

Accept.js gives you control over the user experience using your own form, but avoids any sensitive card data passing through your server.

Comment: Well I'm not trying to send sensitive data to my server. I just want to send the form element to the callback. If there is no way to do that then this is my answer, thank you.

Comment: Accept.js is only for turning sensitive card data into the nonce, it doesn't offer the ability to pass other data.  But since you control the form in your code, after you've send the payment data and have a nonce, you would send the remaining form elements with your POST to your server.